# Any way to JSON.parse a POST in PHP?

Tags: php, json, parsing

I know it can be done in Ruby, but I need to parse an array that's in an array in PHP.

```
POST
{
Payload
{
amount="xxx",
uid="xxx",
actual_amount="xxx"
},
signature
}
```

I can access the Payload by using $_POST['payload'],
But how can I access the elements inside the payload array?
Technically, Payload is a JSON array.
Like this

```
a:2:s:7:"payload";s:61:"{"amount":25,"adjusted_amount":17.0,"uid":"brainiac"}";s:9:"signature";s:40:"fbc4e6081d2d1d5d3894dd26a09c4d6b97c9e591";}
```

If you look closely at the JSON array, you'll notice that the payload array isn't an array at all. It's string! (s:#)

Comment: Hmm... JSON arrays doesn't contains `=`. However: if you got JSON... `$payload = json_decode($_POST['payload']);`?

Comment: That last part is not JSON, it's a PHP serialized variable. See [this answer's comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12021847/451969) for a history of this question, which is not *exactly* what I had in mind. There's something missing that I can't put my finger on.

Comment: @JaredFarrish your codepad shows a vaild serialized string (s:52, i.e. a string of 52 characters which can literally be any characters), which isn't a surprise since a json-encoded array is a string

Comment: @AD7six - Yes, see my answer. It took a minute to process. The point is that double encoding is nonsense, and JSON encoding is simpler and more platform-independent.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I would say the double encoding is the problem - not handling it. Whatever is serializing the data is the error to address, not handling the weird result.

Comment: @AD7six - Yeah yeah, you did read my comment *right above* our last comment? Part of the issue I had was visually reading the string result with the embedded JSON in a PHP serialized variable. It doesn't look right, but it took me a minute or three to "see" it right.

Answer (score 6):

There is a function called [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), which will help you carry this task out.

```
$payload = json_decode($_POST['payload']);
var_dump($payload['amount']); // string(3) "xxx"
```

Comment: Yeah I know, but since Payload is actually a string (notice the s:#), the elements inside payload don't show as parts of an array.

Comment: Your example input does not seem to be a real JSON for me. JSON encoded strings usually look like the following: `'{"amount":"xxx","uid":"xxx","actual_amount":"xxx","signature":"fbc4e6081d2d1d5d3894dd26a09c4d6b97c9e591"}'`. This data must have been created with a special method which needs the same special method, but reversed, to decode it.

Comment: @YinanWang Well, the contents within the "Payload" key, is a string. A JSON-stirng, which you can run json_decode on. The submitted data will be a string (unless you're submitting an array structure using [] in the POST name), and you'll have to validate and parse this in your application.

Comment: @Whisperity The format of the string in the post is a serialize()'d PHP value, so I assume it's an example of how the POST data looks when he calls serialize() on it.

Comment: @Whisperity Are you talking about the first code box, or the second one?

Comment: Considering the example output of Yinan, `serialize()` string looks the following: `'a:2:{s:7:"payload";a:3:{s:6:"amount";i:25;s:15:"adjusted_amount";d:17;s:3:"uid";s:8:"brainiac";}s:9:"signature";s:40:"fbc4e6081d2d1d5d3894dd26a09c4d6b97c9e591";}'`. While `json_encode()` looks like `'{"payload":{"amount":25,"adjusted_amount":17,"uid":"brainiac"},"signature":"fbc4e6081d2d1d5d3894dd26a09c4d6b97c9e591"}'`.

Comment: Ok I've somehow meddled with my program so that now, $payload is in json_encode().

Comment: Now how do I convert that to array? or is it already an array?

Comment: @YinanWing If the input `$_POST['payload']` is a true JSON-encoded string, then see my answer: `$payload = json_decode($_POST['payload']);`. It **is** technically an array, but not a PHP `array` type variable.

Comment: Alright. I have done as you said. When you say technically, you mean that I can't use it in my code, yes?

Comment: @YinanWang Yes. The variable is an `array`, but you can't use that in your PHP code as what the variable is currently is: `$_POST['payload']` being a `json_encode()` created **string**. But this **string** can be converted back to a real, PHP `array` using `json_decode()`, from which, you can access it as any other array. Yes, still, see my answer.

Comment: Whoa! Wait a sec. If encoding makes it a non-usuable array, and decoding makes it a usualble array, why would I encode it in the forst place?

Comment: @YinanWang - Why would you *double-encode* an inner part of the *encoded* part? That's the rub.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Two things: SO I need to json_encode the ENTIRE POST? and second, the answer you posted below won't work, i think. Since the POSTED data isn't controlled by me. SO I don't create the array.

Comment: It's a two-step problem. You either have to accept (the POST), decode the part that is JSON (the `Payload` object), then insert into your table in some form (I recommend JSON here, you could PHP serialize, but don't), OR, serialize and store and then, on view, deserialize twice for each read. The sane way is to do the former, since it only has to occur once before it's been synchronized, then after, where it has to be done *per read*.

Answer (score 1):

I finally think I figured this out. To wit:

```
<?php

$post = array();
$post['array1'] = json_encode(array(
    'info1' => 'test 1',
    'info2' => 'test 2',
    'info3' => 'test 3'
));
$post['info4'] = '#';

echo serialize($post);
echo "\n";
var_dump(unserialize(serialize($post)));

?>
```

http://codepad.org/jaHT6lfW

Gives:

```
a:2:{s:6:"array1";s:52:"{"info1":"test 1","info2":"test 2","info3":"test 3"}";s:5:"info4";s:1:"#";}
array(2) {
  ["array1"]=>
  string(52) "{"info1":"test 1","info2":"test 2","info3":"test 3"}"
  ["info4"]=>
  string(1) "#"
}
```

So:

```
<?php

$post = array();
$post['array1'] = json_encode(array(
    'info1' => 'test 1',
    'info2' => 'test 2',
    'info3' => 'test 3'
));
$post['info4'] = '#';

$serial = serialize($post);
echo "$serial\n";

$unserial = unserialize(serialize($post));
var_dump($unserial);

$unserial['array1'] = json_decode($unserial['array1']);
var_dump($unserial);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/mpfDLyvH

Gives the correct output.

Seriously, just JSON encode it *all*, after consuming the `$_POST` array, before insert it into your database. You won't have to worry about this nonsense if you do so. And your data should really only be serialized with one constant type per field, for sanity's sake.