# Redirect post request to get using PHP

Tags: php, http, post, get

I need a PHP script that gets a POST request and redirects it to another page as a GET request with all parameters in the URL.

Is this possibile?

Comment: Why would you want to do such a thing? Why not just use GET in the first place?

Comment: Because the application that made the request is not mine so I can't change it.

Comment: But you at the very least you own the application *receiving* the request, don't you? So why do you need to redirect the user elsewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/function.http-build-query.php) to generate the GET query string from `$_POST`.

Afterwards attach it to the redirect URL and use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/function.header.php) with Location for the redirect, for example:

```
$newURL = 'http://example.com/script.php?' . http_build_query($_POST);
header("Location: {$newURL}");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$URL = "http://thatpage.com/thatpage.php?";
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    $URL +="$key=$value&";
}
```

then open that $URL page

Comment: Same solution as mine ;) you do not need to iterate and concat string just use the internal function.

Comment: @JensPeters, could be, yes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse the $_POST variable in order to create a complete GET URL

This question could help you to parse the $_POST array
[PHP Parse $_POST Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12021817/php-parse-post-array)

Comment: Something like this? foreach($_POST as $name=>$value)
{
 $params=$params. "&". $name. "=". $value;
}

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
{
    $getString .= $k . '=' . $v . '&';
}
```

should format the POSTed variables in the proper format.

Comment: Ooops, missed that there! ;)